# Delete row in SQLite database with python where with two conditions

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to python and SQLite and I hope you can help me. I'm trying to figure out how to delete a row in  a SQLite database, for what I have two conditions.

This is roughly how my code looks:

```
a.execute("""Create Table xxx (
Data,
ID,
Date)""")

a.execute("Insert into xxx values (?, ?, ?)", (data, ID , date)""")
```

My problem is that a lot of data is going into the database and the ID is not distinct. If there are two ore more datasets with the same ID, I want to only keep the one with the latest date)

I tried it with this code:

```
a.execute ("""delete from xxx
where date not in(
Select max(date) from xxx
group by ID
```

But the problem is, it doesn't delete anything, probably because every date is in there.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I would say to try to write a select first that retruns the rows you want to delete. Then you can convert it to delete.

Comment: This is a good article for your requirement.
https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/

Comment: Are you calling `connection.commit()` to persist the changes?

Comment: Also, there is a problem with your strategy where the maximum date for one ID might also be the date of another row with a different ID. Such rows won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query to check if the row's date is not equal to the maximum result. Additionally, you should update your subquery to only include rows where the id is the same as the one from the main deletion query:

```
delete from xxx t1 
where t1.date != (select max(t2.date) from xxx t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM xxx AS x1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM xxx AS x2 WHERE x2.ID = x1.ID AND x2.Date > x1.Date)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8be9ed9d38d572de4d730e36ffff32ea).